# scrollspy active class flickers with AJAX

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Scrollspy is causing my li to flicker between the first and second li when I scroll down the page, but once I get to the last section the correct li becomes active. I'm pretty sure this has to do something with AJAX, but can't figure out why. When I refresh the page scrollspy works perfectly. Any ideas why this is happening? I've tried everything with no success.

Body tag

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".stickysteps">
```

How scrollspy is called

```
<% if manual.present? && manual.steps.present? %> 
<div class="stickysteps">
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <% n = 0 %>
    <% @manual.steps.order(:priority).each do |step| %>
        <li><a href="#step<%= n+1 %>"><h4>Step <%= n + 1 %></h4></a></li>
        <% n += 1 %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<h1 style="margin-left: 20px;">Your Instructions:</h1> </br>
<% steps = manual.steps.order(:priority) %>
<%= render(steps.order(:priority), steps: steps) %>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.stickysteps').scrollspy(); 
$('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
$('.stickysteps').scrollspy('refresh');
});

offsetValue = 168;
$('body').data().scrollspy.options.offset = offsetValue;
// force scrollspy to recalculate the offsets to your targets
$('body').data().scrollspy.process();
</script>

<%= javascript_include_tag "manuals" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "imagezoom" %>
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your jQuery functions in a document.ready statement? The page may not be fully loaded when your scripts run hence a flickering effet.

Comment: What is the purpose of the each on the second line of your javascript? it's running the refresh method on all stickysteps elements n times which probably is not intended.

Comment: Yeah that could be. That's what boostraps documentation says to do. "When using scrollspy in conjunction with adding or removing of elements from the DOM, you'll need to call the refresh method like so:

$('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
  var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh')
});"

Comment: With that added, only the last step is highlighted the entire time